# What auth do i need to secure WebAPI 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a website which is returning 1000s of rows to display for a public frontend.

I am using dataTables (https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) for the website where i am getting some data from a C# WebAPI 2 **which has been created by ourselves** returning JSON data.

This table then uses other attributes to set the style for the button etc and the row/cell associated values.

Considering this is publicly available, i would like to add some form of authentication to the WebAPI. After researching around most are using Identity but this project doesnt use Identity.

I then read about JWT (Json Web Token i believe) but no working examples for me to attempt or broken links.

Came across Base64 but as i understood it cant be utilised with Https protocol which this WebAPI would eventually be going towards.

Some other articles seem to be relating to .Net Core version which im not using.

Is there a simple way of me protecting this Web API, if so what type of auth do i require?

Comment: Please tell us what your _threat-model_ is: who are you trying to protect data _from_ and who are you intending to be able to access it? (e.g. If it's just a single client then I'd use mutual-authentication with both Client-side and Server-side certificates; but if it's a (very) public service then I'd likely have zero authentication/authorization (and I'd let the NLB do the rate-limiting for me) or have a simple per-user "API key" set-up using a simple `.json`/`.xml` configuration file for the web-service. For anything in-between then _it's complicated_...

Comment: @Dai Its just to stop anyone from accessing the data directly from the WebAPI and then saving that data into their own systems. I know they could still do this via the website but the format wouldnt be as easy as the data provided from the WebAPI

Answer (score 2):

So, what you *need* will depend on your requirements. But, typically for publicly available APIs OAuth2 OpenID Connect are used.

And to differentiate:

- [OpenID connect](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/protocols/openid-connect-protocol) (which is on top of OAuth2) when dealing with users,
- [OAuth2](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/protocols/oauth) when using [machine to machine (service to service) authentication](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/actions/flows-and-triggers/machine-to-machine-flow).

Publicly available is different for publicly used.
If you don't have actual customer - or have a form of a close network (over internet), you could do with mutual certificates access and that sort.

Going for OpenID c or OAuth - there are a couple of providers:

- Identity Server 4 (keep track of lifecycle on this one, a lot have changed last year)
- [Auth0](https://auth0.com/). A SaaS solution - currently having a free tier
- [AWS cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/)
- [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview)
- Surely Google cloud has one as well.

As an example for Auth0, they provide (a possibly outdated example) on [their website](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-core-2):

##### EXAMPLE TAKEN FROM AUTH0 FOR CONTEXT - PLEASE VALIDATE

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Cookie configuration for HTTP to support cookies with SameSite=None
    services.ConfigureSameSiteNoneCookies();

    // Cookie configuration for HTTPS
    // services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    // {
    //     options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    // });

    // Add authentication services
    services.AddAuthentication(options => {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options => {
        // Set the authority to your Auth0 domain
        options.Authority = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}";

        // Configure the Auth0 Client ID and Client Secret
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Auth0:ClientSecret"];

        // Set response type to code
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;

        // Configure the scope
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");

        // Set the callback path, so Auth0 will call back to http://localhost:3000/callback
        // Also ensure that you have added the URL as an Allowed Callback URL in your Auth0 dashboard
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/callback");

        // Configure the Claims Issuer to be Auth0
        options.ClaimsIssuer = "Auth0";
    });

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}

}
```

Source: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-core-2

Comment: Ok quite a bit involved. I assume with those links referring to Core it should still be ok with WebAPI 2. I will have a read first to see whats involved etc

Comment: Well, yes, here are more examples on OAuth2: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstarts
If you require a specific template OWIN or similar, you should look for older implementations. I must say, they can be hard to find - but the concept still is the same.

Comment: Oh, wait - they even have OWIN on there XD